# Excel formula that omits 0's and #N/A to find Min

Tags: excel

Is there a function I can put in excel that will find the minimum value for the range "F3:G36" and ignore any cells that contain "#N/A" or 0? I'm basically looking for the 2nd lowest number in the range while omitting the #N/A's in my search.
I have tried different combinations of Min(If(Isnumber(etc...) but it only returns #N/A as a value. I cannot change the vlookup formulas in the cells.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER:**

=SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(F3:G36),IF(F3:G36>0,F3:G36)),2)

This will return the 2nd lowest number and avoid errors and 0s.