# Excel : combined MIN + IF with 0 or #N/A

Tags: excel, nan, min

This is my problem.
I'm trying to use a MIN and IF combinaison (with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**) because I'm looking for the minimum number of a list that respects a condition, but I don't want MIN returns a 0. Just the value other 0.
The function, that works with MAX, is the following : `{=MIN(IF(B1:B5<C1;1;0)*A1:A5)}`

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 202.2 | 200 |
| 2 | 11 | 201.5 |  |
| 3 | 12 | 200.3 |  |
| 4 | 13 | 199.5 |  |
| 5 | 14 | 198.0 |  |

`{=MIN(IF(B1:B5<C1;1;0)*A1:A5)}` returns 0, while `{=MIN(IF(B1:B5<C1;1;NA())*A1:A5)}` returns an error. I also tried the function SMALL like I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812484/excel-formula-that-omits-0s-and-n-a-to-find-min) but it seems not work neither.

The function `{=MAX(IF(B1:B5>C1;1;0)*A1:A5)}` works well (because 0 is not the max of course). Another way for me to have the result should be to get the number of the following index of the MAX function. But, here again, I don't know how to do.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Use: `=MIN(IF(B1:B5<C1,A1:A5,""))`

Comment: I don't understand why you need to enter a *value_if_false* clause at all for the IF function. Simply `=MIN(IF(B1:B5<C1,A1:A5))`. Boolean FALSEs are ignored by `MIN`.

Comment: Your issue is that you are taking the *product* of your array condition and the entries in `B1:B5`, which will result in a *numeric zero* for rows which do not match the condition specified. Zeroes are not ignored by `MIN`, whereas Boolean FALSEs are.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I better understand now!